# Does MOND reduce the discrepancy in a quantifiable way?

Tags: modified-gravity

Which of the following statements accurately describes the impact of Modified Newtonian Dynamics (MOND) on the observed "missing baryonic mass" discrepancy in galaxy clusters?

1. MOND is a theory that reduces the observed missing baryonic mass in galaxy clusters by postulating the existence of a new form of matter called "fuzzy dark matter."
2. MOND is a theory that increases the discrepancy between the observed missing baryonic mass in galaxy clusters and the measured velocity dispersions from a factor of around 10 to a factor of about 20.
3. MOND is a theory that explains the missing baryonic mass in galaxy clusters that was previously considered dark matter by demonstrating that the mass is in the form of neutrinos and axions.
4. MOND is a theory that reduces the discrepancy between the observed missing
   baryonic mass in galaxy clusters and the measured velocity
   dispersions from a factor of around 10 to a factor of about 2.
5. MOND is a theory that eliminates the observed missing baryonic mass
   in galaxy clusters by imposing a new mathematical formulation of
   gravity that does not require the existence of dark matter.

We were arguing about this, and someone said 4 is wrong even though that's what it says in the wikipedia page for MOND.  They are arguing that MOND doesn't really reduce the discrepancy in a quantifiable way.

They are saying that 5 is supposedly a better answer.

We were hoping folks here could help let us know if wikipedia is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point 1 is obviously wrong. MOND and fuzzy dark matter are different things, since the latter is a type of dark matter and MOND is a modified theory of gravity. Point 2 is also wrong, since MOND reduces the discrepancy, not increases it. Point 3 is a variant of point 1 - neutrinos are not fuzzy dark matter, but axions would qualify.

So that leaves points 4 and 5. MOND definitely reduces the need for dark matter, but it doesn't eliminate it entirely. On the other hand, a much-smaller amount of dark matter is easier to explain in mundane terms - it could for example just be black holes, dust, or planets that don't shine, etc. Hence both 4 and 5 are correct, they just describe MOND differently.